# how to configure default bucket in sagemaker pipeline?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am doing some experimentation in training models in amazon sagemaker/studio via sagemaker piplines. based on samples/aws docs , in my notebook ( sample code below) , in my jupyter notebook, i set up sagemaker session , execution role via code like shown below . also, there is a default bucket that is set up =>  sess.default_bucket(),

how is this default bucket configured? or can we simply point to the one we want?

```
import sagemaker
import os
try:
    sess = sagemaker.Session()
    role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
except ValueError:
    import boto3
    # creates a boto3 session using the local profile we defined
    if local_profile_name:
        os.environ['AWS_PROFILE'] = local_profile_name # setting env var bc local-mode cannot use boto3 session
        #bt3 = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=local_profile_name)
        #iam = bt3.client('iam')
        # create sagemaker session with boto3 session
        #sess = sagemaker.Session(boto_session=bt3)
    iam = boto3.client('iam')
    sess = sagemaker.Session()
    # get role arn
    role = iam.get_role(RoleName=role_name)['Role']['Arn']


   print(sess.default_bucket()) # s3 bucketname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the pipeline context, [PipelineSession](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html#sagemaker.workflow.pipeline_context.PipelineSession) should be used wherever possible.

> This class inherits the SageMaker session, it provides convenient
> methods for manipulating entities and resources that Amazon SageMaker
> uses, such as training jobs, endpoints, and input datasets in S3. When
> composing SageMaker Model-Building Pipeline, PipelineSession is
> recommended over regular SageMaker Session

At this point, you can specify the bucket directly as a parameter:

```py
from sagemaker.workflow.pipeline_context import PipelineSession

pipeline_session = PipelineSession(default_bucket = your_default_bucket)
```

Comment: Does each sagemaker session has its own default bucket or all sessions share same default bucket? Also if later is true, then  do all notebook instances have same default bucket?

Comment: From the [doc](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/utility/session.html): "When you make an Amazon SageMaker API call that accesses an S3 bucket location and one is not specified, the Session creates a default bucket based on a naming convention which includes the current AWS account ID." So, it's unique based on account and not notebook instance or session.